# Find value automatically using the formula (Dump and connector) or cell address in excel 2013

Tags: excel-formula, ms-office, excel-2013

I am trying to get the "video duration" from the "video id" in MS Excel 2013. It is the YouTube video. I am using SEOTools (third party plugin) for it. Kindly find the attached screenshot of excel 2013. The Video Ids are the YouTube Ids in the column A. I want an automatic formula. So, it can easily find the video duration by using the video id.

For a single result, the formula is mentioned below:

=Dump(Connector("YouTube.VideoStatistics","**HviM15ZY8**","Duration",FALSE))

The "HviM15ZY8" is a single Youtube video id. I want to do it automatic using cell address.

Can anyone help me? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: `=Dump(Connector("YouTube.VideoStatistics",$A2,"Duration",FALSE))` ??

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor thank you so much! It is working superbly. Thanks, mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=Dump(Connector("YouTube.VideoStatistics",$A2,"Duration",FALSE))`